# onTouch and onClick

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to make an app and this thing is breaking my brain. The user has to choose 1 of the 12 ImageViews I have. If it's the correct but user only touch it for less than 3 seconds a normal message shows. BUT if he/she touches it for more than 3 seconds it trigger a new and different message.

The thing is I have an onClickListener to get the TAG of the ImageView the user clicks and I compare it with the correct one. If its correct it has also to do the next work: 
Has the user touched it for more than 3 seconds? if yes show a message if not show a different one.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.btLogOut){    //this one is to see if the user clicked the logout Button
            DBH.deletePerson();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(Fake.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

       if(v.getTag().equals("the one who waits for the on touch")){
        ImageView x = (ImageView)findViewById(v.getId());
        x.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        lastDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        lastDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastDown;
                        cambio(lastDuration);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }


             public void cambio(long ld){  //check time it has been touched
                    if (ld > 3000) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        lastDuration = 0;

                    }

                    if (ld < 1000) {
                        lastDuration = 0;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                });
```

The main problem I'm having is: when i touch for the first time to the correct imageView it doesn't enters in the onTouch, only in the onClick.
Do you guys know any better idea to implement this?

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: try using `onLongClickListener`

Answer (score 1):

1. `return true` in `ACTION_DOWN` event to get notified for `ACTION_UP` event
2. Handle `ACTION_CANCEL` event too and treat it as `ACTION_UP`.
3. You can count the time interval between `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` and ignore touches that are longer than `x` seconds.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that i need the onClick listeners because if user clicks another button/Imageview a message/action will be done. So i need my app to listen to the clicks BUT when user clicks the ImageView whose tag is the same I give i want this ImageView to listen to the time it has been down.

Comment: That's fine. You are doing it right. Just return true in onTouch and follow the other 2 points above.